# How to gain permission to get GPS location in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-gps

I am new to Android and in my current project I am trying to retrieve location using GPS. The code for obtaining the location is in a separate non-activity class, because the fragment where I display the coordinates is crammed.

I have tried to use the guidelines from developer.android.com but I can't get any permission prompt, and when I press the button in the fragment, I only get the default 0-values for latitude and longitude.

I have provided the permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The GPS locator class:

```
public class LocationProvider implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    private Activity activity;

    Location gps_loc;
    Location final_loc;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationProvider(Activity activity) {
        this.activity =activity;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            // Request for permission.
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLocation();
            } else {
                requestLocationPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        // Check if the permission has been granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (gps_loc != null) {
                Log.v("Loc_provider",gps_loc.toString());
                final_loc = gps_loc;
                latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
                longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
            }
        } else {
            requestLocationPermission();
        }
    }


    private void requestLocationPermission() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }


    public String getCoordinates() {
        return latitude + " "+ longitude;
    }
}
```

The code in the fragment:

```
FloatingActionButton fab=view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                locProvider=new LocationProvider(requireActivity());
                gpsCoordinates.setText(locProvider.getCoordinates());
            }
        });
```

Tips and solutions for fixing the code are most welcome.

**UPDATE 1:**
I moved the code in the fragment instead, so that it looks like below:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission()) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                } else {
                    gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    gpsCoordinates.setText(getCoordinates());
                    }
                }
        });

private String getCoordinates() {
        if (gps_loc != null) {
            Log.v("Loc_provider", gps_loc.toString());
            final_loc = gps_loc;
            latitude = gps_loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps_loc.getLongitude();
        }
        return latitude + " " + longitude;
    }

    private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Log.v("Grant_Results", String.valueOf(grantResults[0]));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    gpsCoordinates.setText(getCoordinates());
                    } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                break;
                }
            }
    }
```

I now get the permission prompt, but the location still doesn't update (I get 0).

Comment: Just delete the space before ACCESS  **. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />**

Comment: Has no effect whatsoever unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by implementing LocationListener in Fragment and then adding

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, this);
```

in onRequestPermissionsResult().

Answer (score 1):

Please note:

1. Saving an Activity object is not recommended this may cause memory leaks. Activity may be destroyed and recreated (for example when screen orientation changes). Holding a reference to the old activity will cause you problems.
2. Implementing the `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` interface does nothing. Your method will never be called. You will have to call it explicitly from the activity.
3. You have not requested permission, so your permission prompt will never be shown and the default value of `double` that is 0 will get returned. You need to call your `getLocation()` method so that the control falls on the else block and your permission prompt is shown

I recommend you handle permission in the activity. Have the activity get the coordinates for the location. You can have the activity implement an interface, say `LocationFetcher`, with a method `getCoordinates()`. You can then call this in the fragment like so:

```
LocationFetcher locationFetcher = (LocationFetcher) activity;
gpsCoordinates.setText(locationFetcher.getCoordinates());
```

Comment: Let me know if you get what I am trying to say. If not, ill help you with the code

Comment: Thanks. I've tried implementing the code in the onClick()- method. If i uninstall the app and reinstall, I get permission request, however I still don't get the coordinates updated, I only get 0. Can you please help?

Comment: Fixed it now. .